# How to deal with serial editors that distort the original meaning of the question or an answer?

Tags: discussion, edits

A user has recently started being extremely actively in editing the questions and answers in the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag. Sometimes even answering the now *different* question.

An example of bad answer editing: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11497391/revisions

An example of bad question editing: [How do I specify new lines in Python, for writing files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11497376/251311)

There are plenty of examples in their history. And most of changes alter the meaning of the post or wipe out good details.

Comment: Calling out other users specifically is not appreciated on Meta (seek general policy clarification). I've edited the link out but left revisions in for context.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine it's a problem with a particular user too: I cannot report their action with any available mechanism.

Comment: @zerkms You can flag one of their posts and explain in detail the issue in a custom mod flag (including stuff like links to provide evidence).

Comment: It is doubtful that the problem in question requires mention of a specific user, @zerkms. And as Nick mentioned above, if you want to make a complaint about an editor continuously making incorrect edits, you can do so by flagging one of their posts for mod attention. Calling out users on Meta just causes unnecessary drama.

Comment: More on point, after looking at the first edit you are complaining about, I do not see how it changes the meaning of the post or wipes good details. If anything, the edit reduces unnecessary chit-chat while preserving the crux: either add newlines or use the `os` module.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine they changed it again 2 minutes ago, see the timeline. The original edit was bad and I asked them in the comments to stop it, so they reverted it.

Comment: @zerkms huh. Rev 4 was the latest when I opened the post (which is expected given that the rollback happened just now), consider the above to be said about the rev 4, apologies. Still, why do you think the edit was bad?

Comment: The question edit was bad because it changed the essence of a question that had been active for 10 years. 

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11497376/revisions

The question was modified in a way that changed it. When asking the question I didn't know what a line break was, and I was coming from a different language. I didn't have the words to describe what I wanted. 

The modified answers are like this too, the original answer mentioned the os python module, and mentioned linesep, this is different from just giving os.linesep

Comment: The original spiel of the answer was right with the original spiel of the question

Comment: Not sure about the question edit, but still can't get a grasp on what's wrong with the answer edit. It does not omit the name of the `os` module, and changes the link to point to the relevant documentation part. What's the benefit of linking to `os` as a whole for other readers? In addition, the removed text doesn't add any valuable information because it doesn't specify what "right" and "how correct" means, as is that part of the answer is chit-chat.

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine For me the difference between "always use this" and "use this until this" answers is significant. But I already spent too much time on the problem :shrug:

Comment: "Write strings that are separated by \n to the file." did not answer my question. If I had seen that 10 years ago I woulda just said... well thats what my question already had, where does \n come from. 

The edit to the question made it as if I knew what a line break was, then the answer edit included that.

The original answer lead me to the right way.

Comment: "An example of bad answer editing" It looks like the editor in question rolled the edit back after this Meta post.

Comment: "An example of bad question editing" The question shouldn't mention Java at all, because it is not useful for understanding the problem.  If the question was really "what is the Python equivalent of `\r\n` in a Java string literal?", then it makes no sense to ask; the most obvious thing to try is `\r\n`, and *if it caused a problem, the question should have been about that instead*. "How do I represent a new line in a string?" is, despite being a much easier question, also a much more reasonable one - because we can infer that the asker doesn't already know.

Comment: "When asking the question I didn't know what a line break was, and I was coming from a different language. I didn't have the words to describe what I wanted." I can't quite understand this. At the time, what exactly did you think the `\r\n` thing was called in the Java code, or what it meant? Why would "try doing the same thing" not be the first debugging step in the Python code?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel "then it makes no sense to ask;" --- it makes no sense to ask if you _already know_ and don't understand something. Imagine a _hypothetical_ case when someone asked about `print()` function in REPL and **did not** try sending `None` and `(None, None)` as an input before asking. Isn't it the first debugging step right?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel have to try and reach back into my brain from 10 years ago lol. But, I must have ran into some issue with \r, and didn't really know what either \r or \n even were, or what \ did vs r, they were just parts of a string that I would have seen in Java.

Comment: One thing that I do know though, is that I didn't understand what was going on with these characters, I knew they were hidden somehow, but I didn't know what a line break was. The whole question wouldn't have been asked I think if I had known to ask about a "line break".

Comment: The question title already contained "New lines" (In fact the first revision had it in the question body too) in it which is synonymous to "line break", if one didn't know what `\r\n` did they won't be asking for an equivalent. At most the "line break" should have been replaced with "new line" and that was a good edit. I don't see how any of the edits mentioned here were bad.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat that user has series of edits, no reason to focus on just one of them: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70275607/revisions Here half of the data from the question is removed.

Comment: @zerkms again the edit you linked seems fine to me, admittedly they did change the code the OP had provided and also removed an image but they kept the intent of the question (while making it concise), standardized the code to use a publicly available dataset instead and removed an image that really didn't convey what the OP wanted to convey (And all of this was done without breaking the existing answer).

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat "while making it concise" --- that's not always the best thing to do: if you don't know the topic - you search using less specific/concise terms. If a question is written "naturally" - it's higher chance to be found by people with similar problem *and* similar experience.

Comment: "you search using less specific/concise terms" for that we have duplicates, that question isn't one. Also, the title is the most important thing for users looking at questions, rather than the body.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I think most users on Stack Overflow are genuinely trying to be helpful. This is especially true for users with more than 2000 reputation who are making edits. What impetus would they have otherwise?

If you think someone is making edits that are not optimal, I think it is reasonable to contact them. [You can @notify editors with a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) under the edited post. I've had dozens to hundreds of productive exchanges with users all over the site. I've also learned much from users commenting on my edits / user moderation actions.

However, please keep in mind 2 things before leaving the comment:

1. Don't necessarily jump immediately to a rollback. For edits that aren't blatantly destructive, it's not like it's an emergency. That has a strong potential to get things off on the wrong foot.
2. When commenting, be *very* careful not to be overly accusatory. Be friendly, and try to stick to the facts.

You might try leaving a comment like this:

> Hi @BobTheEditor, improving questions and answers on Stack Overflow with edits is appreciated. However, I worry that your most recent [edit](https://www.stackoverflow.com) (link to revision) may have altered the question in a way that invalidates existing answers. As [noted in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-suggested-edits), edits shouldn't fundamentally alter the question. Perhaps we could edit back in the part about `foo`-ing the `bar`, that way the existing answers still make sense.

Now, wait. Remember, not everyone uses the site all day, every day, and they live in timezones all over the world. Again, we're talking about a non-emergency.

Hopefully the editor will see the error of their ways, edit the post, and all will be a success. Maybe they will want to have a brief exchange with you to clarify. Just be sure that the comments don't turn into a full discussion. You can always continue the discussion in chat if necessary. Remember: if the edit is resolved successfully, delete your comments and flag any discussing the edit as "no longer needed"; they have served their purpose.

However, **if things get heated, just disengage.** It's not worth causing drama. Just flag any offensive comments, delete your own, and flag the edited post for moderator attention. As noted in the comments above, be sure to explain things in as much detail as possible. Moderators are not subject matter experts in every language, so you need to make your case fully.

This may be a lot of work, but hopefully the user will make more helpful edits in the future.

Comment: The immediate rollback, I rolled back the edits on my own question (the one in question), is the author free to keep the contents of the question? Or should I have notified the editor instead?  I didn't think flagging the question would have been better than rolling back because there wasn't a problem with the question itself. It would have been good if I could flag a specific edit revision instead. 

I saw that the user who edited the question & top answer had rolled back the answer too on their own after the question rollback.

Comment: @FabianCook That comment wasn’t intended to be directed at you, just the general case. As the question author, I think you have a bit more leeway when the issue is changing the intent of the question. After all, who knows your intent better than yourself? I think you’re much less likely to create a rollback war if you leave them a comment first. You can also make use of the edit reason. If you leave a comment and can remember, try to delete the comment later. If you need to, you can link the revision directly in the custom flag text. You’ll need a custom one to explain anyway.

Comment: @FabianCook note, that if the community feels that at large it is more served by having something else but your exact wording, it will waive your preferences for the greater good.

Comment: @Braiam [*The greater good*](https://i.imgur.com/aFhWSah.mp4).

Comment: I disagree with the advice not to rollback. It's the simplest and most effective way to fix an issue with a problematic edit, so why not use it? If the post needs further editing, sure, make a more nuanced edit by hand, but if none of the edit is good and it all needs to be reverted, that's literally what the rollback option is for.

Comment: But how is it determined that really a post needs further editing? In this case the question + accepted answer had already been seen by 2 million plus people, both the question and accepted answer has 400 plus upvotes on them, with only 5 to 6 downvotes, surely that there alone is saying that this post probably doesn't need further edits.

.... but its now also the reverse, for me as the author I have to decide as well, that the edit was actually needing editing, or, if the edit was just a bit extra. 

The very first version of my title was "New line python".... now look at it

Answer (score 10):

> https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11497391/revisions

To my mind, I see nothing wrong with revision #4. The edit which changes original authorial intent is revision #2. Revision #1 recommends `os.linesep` over `\n`. Revision #2 edits it to add a section saying that `\n` is preferable to `os.linesep`.

This is contradictory advice - [it shouldn't be an edit, it should be an entirely new answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317632/is-it-ok-to-edit-someones-wrong-answer). As written, this revision doesn't really make sense. It says that if you "really want to get it right," you should use `os.linesep`. But if you're "writing to files using the Python api," then you should use `\n`. But if you're writing to a file in Python, you are always using the Python API.

Then, revision #4 comes and changes the contradictory answer to have a single, unambiguous meaning. But now, the meaning of the answer is the opposite of revision #1.

However, I would not expect people editing an answer to read the entire revision history before editing. That's not reasonable. When I edit, I generally assume that the editors who came before me preserved original intent.

Comment: "I generally assume that the editors who came before me preserved original intent" I generally presume that they made the post better. Also, the documentation is unambiguous as it is: use \n in all cases, specially do not use os.linesep if you open files in text mode, which is the default. The revision 1 said something to the same tune except the note about text mode.

Comment: @Braiam I want to be clear: I'm not talking about the *correctness* of Rev #1. If we're talking about correctness, then it is best to open a file in text mode and use \n. So Rev #1 is wrong in recommending os.linsep over \n. The issue is: if there's a wrong answer, should you edit the answer to make it right? `The revision 1 said something to the same tune` Maybe this is subjective, but I don't see that reading of Rev #1. It seems to say that \n will work, but os.linesep is more "correct."

Comment: I'm not talking about correctness either, I'm talking about semantic equivalence. Both revisions are semantically equivalent: they say the same thing as the documentation. If both say the same thing as the documentation with variations of how much of the documentation they reflect, then the "meaning" was no altered.

Answer (score 6):

If a user edits someone else's question to ask something different, it should be rolled back because changing the author's intent is not allowed. If *anyone* edits a question to ask something different in a way that invalidates existing answers, it should be rolled back because invalidating existing content that way is also not allowed. Likewise, great care should be taken when editing another user's answer to make it say something different in terms of the solution it gives. *Typically* such edits should be comment suggestions or just entirely new answers, instead.

If you notice a user doing this on or two times, rollback the content and consider leaving a comment note addressing the issues with such edits.

If you notice a user doing this to a large extent or as a pattern of behavior, flag one of their posts or one of the affected/edited posts for moderator attention and request that they take a look, or, preferably, that you have serious concerns that you need to go in-depth on and request a moderator create a private chatroom. In a private chatroom, you can chat as much as you like (unlike the grotesquely short limit on mod flag character count) and only you + the site moderators can see the chatroom, let alone its contents.

Answer (score 2):

> And most of changes alter the meaning of the post or wipe out good details.

The better something gets, the higher the chances that any well meant change is not further improving but sometimes also decreasing the quality of the content. The reason is that people make mistakes or have different opinions. And this is without assuming any bad intent.

To avoid lowering the quality by simply accumulating noise edits, we should become more picky about edits the more popular some content becomes. On the other hand content can age, so updating it is still vital. We should always allow content to be edited.

Short of edit review queues for changes to popular content and an edit reputation (for example ratio of well received edits to not well received edits) I hardly see what else can be done (additionally to what is existing and can be done by asking for clarification first, then rollbacks if necessary or finally moderator attention flagging).